# how to hide Automatic add-to-cart modal confirmation after a few seconds (prestashop 8)

Tags: popup, hide, cart, shopping-cart, prestashop-1.7

When a user click on add-to-cart-buton, a modal windows appear for confirrmation.
this is not necessary.
i would like hide automaticly the modal confirmation add-to-cart after a few seconds (prestashop 8).

i'm looking for script or addon. I'm using prestashop 8

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Find the add to cart button and attach a click event
    $('.add-to-cart').on('click', function() {
        // Show the confirmation modal or element
        $('#confirmation-modal').modal('show');

        // After 3 seconds (3000 milliseconds), hide the modal
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('#confirmation-modal').modal('hide');
        }, 3000); // Adjust the time delay (in milliseconds) as needed
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you, but where should I put this code ?
in which file ?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).